# Including huge json data into html page

Tags: javascript, html, json, web

Am parsing the json storing it as a variable in my html. 
For smaller JSON's it works fine, but actually the json size would be mostly around 400 mb which is not at all loading the page.

Can someone please suggest the best way to keep the json and access it?

Comment: Loading that much data is never a good idea. Even if you upload it somewhere and fetch it with JavaScript, you still will degrade the performance of the page.

Comment: What's the schema of this JSON?  Hopefully line-delimited....